# How to bind UserControl to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding

I'm having a bit of a trouble connecting both components:

**View:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CoolPlaces.Views.ListItem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewModel}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

Part of **Main Page View:** in which I include above user control:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <views:ListItem Height="300" />
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
namespace CoolPlaces.ViewModels
{
    public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<BasicModel> _places;

        public ObservableCollection<BasicModel> Places {
            get {
                return _places;
            }
            set {
                _places = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Places");
            }
        }

        public ListViewModel() { 
            Places = new ObservableCollection<BasicModel>(_loadPlaces());
        }

        private IEnumerable<BasicModel> _loadPlaces() {
            return //some hard coded objects
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage**

```
namespace CoolPlaces
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private ListViewModel vm;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new ListViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. You need to set the DataContext equal to your ViewModel.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private ListViewModel vm;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = vm = new ListViewModel();
    }
}
```

Then your `ListBox` doesn't need to be bound to it. Instead, bind it to your `Places` property on your ViewModel:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}">
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but it still won't work. Btw. how does my ListItem view know I'm binding to places property on ListViewModel?